# Could iOS disallow apps from looking at the clipboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, security

I heard that TikTok was banned in some countries and was found to be looking at user's clipboard data at times and possibly transferring or storing them some where. But it seems to me any OS could simply not allow the app to do that, be it macOS, Windows, or iOS... user can be copy and pasting in their email app, and when you go to another app, why should the OS allow any app to look into the clipboard data?

Is there any reason for the operating system to allow programs to view the clipboard not in response to the paste command?

What functionality is enabled by allowing programs to view the clipboard not in response to a paste command?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110292/discussion-on-question-by-nonopolarity-could-ios-disallow-apps-from-looking-at-t).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the cut-n-paste functionality, programs will at some point eventually have to read the clipboard contents.

The operating system (on iOS or macOS) in general cannot know what the "paste action" actually is. In some programs it could be clicking/tapping an icon, it could be pressing a keyboard combination (not necessarily the standard one), or it could be programmatically triggered.

However the operating system could trigger a popup asking the user whether to allow a paste operation, when the app accesses the clipboard contents. Or it could show some other indication that the clipboard is being accessed. This is what happens in iOS 14 with a small notification that the clipboard contents was copied.

Note that the operating system cannot as such know whether this popup is being triggered after the user pressed/clicked "Paste", or there is some other reason!

There are other reasons for accessing the clipboard than purely "paste" operations. Some apps for example detect that you have in the clipboard and display certain actions for the user. For example if you have a link in your clipboard, and you start up a link manager app, it could offer easy access to add that link into its database.

Another example is the Facebook app that back in 2015 introduced an automatic "share" suggestion when you have a link in your clipboard.

In iOS 14, Apple has added functionality to allow app developers to ask if the clipboard contains a link that matches a certain pattern without actually accessing the clipboard contents and triggering the popup. This could allow apps to keep their helpful clipboard features without the same privacy impact.

Comment: "The operating system (on iOS or macOS) in general cannot know what the 'paste action' actually is." ...So the iPhone is too stupid to know the difference between a user physically tapping a button on the screen and a hacker stealing clipboard info. Really comforting to know.

Comment: Check out my CLOSED question to find out why this is a huge concern: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431483/

Comment: @Mentalist If you research this, you’ll find that this is not because the operating system is “stupid”, but rather that it is actually impossible to let applications choose their own methods for activating paste and detecting whether a paste is user initiated. This is why ALL operating systems that allow that have the same drawback. The only way to get rid of the drawback is for the operating system to dictate a certain way of activating pastes. This has until not been chosen by any of the main stream operating systems, as it would remove features that many are used to and rely on.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation. Is there any reason though, why Apple couldn't add an authorization step? Such as: `Allow "App Name" to access your clipboard?` I don't see what's difficult about that. It's implemented for camera and location data access. I don't see why the clipboard should be any different. [Documentation on developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources) Forgive my persistence, it's just that I'm shocked that Apple hasn't recognized and remedied this huge vulnerability.

Comment: One more thing to point out re: *"In iOS 14, Apple has added functionality to allow app developers to ask if the clipboard contains a link that matches a certain pattern without actually accessing the clipboard contents and triggering the popup."* This actually allows apps to be sneakier, because they can check to see if the clipboard contains data they've already stolen, and if so, refrain from triggering the popup unnecessarily. This way they can be more discreet, and only steal data that's new to them.

Comment: @Mentalist Sure, technically you could add an authoriation step, so that when pasting from the clipboard, the user gets a popup from the operating system that they need to confirm. There's a tradeoff however. Many user's would be annoyed when that when they click "Paste" they have to click yet another time to acknowledge that they actually mean it and allow it. Note that this is a different question than the one asked in this particular question - i.e. this is not about detecting a user-initated paste operation, but rather just asking for permission every single time. [...]

Comment: [...] Note also that this is not done by other, mainstream operating systems either. When you copy/paste on Android, on Windows, on Linux, etc. you'll not be asked each time if you approve. That would be more secure, but it would also be a hassle. The convention has so far been than whenever the user copies something from a specific program and into the general, system pasteboard - it is made freely available to the system in general. On macOS (but not many other systems) there's ways of copy/pasting in a secure fashion by placing the data on a paste board that is private, and by marking [...]

Comment: [...] the data as transient and confidential. It's up to the app developer however if they want to implement that. Note also that iOS gives the user a warning when an app copies from the paste board, so the user will know if another app has snooped on their data. iOS implemented this before Android did.

Comment: Regarding your second comment that the new functionality allows apps to be sneakier and only steal data that is new to them - this is based on a misunderstanding of that new feature. It does not work that way, and it will not allow the app to be "sneaky" like you describe. It is NOT so that the app supplies a pattern for the system to check the pasteboard against - so the app cannot specify that it wants to check for a pattern like "https://www.facebook.com/". The app can only choose between a few, simple, system provided, built-in patterns. So it can ask whether the pasteboard currently [...]

Comment: [...] holds a URL - but it cannot check if it is a new URL, an URL for a specific site, or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

> Could iOS disallow apps from looking at the clipboard?

No, it can't.
Since iOS 14, it can display a warning.

> Is there any reason for the operating system to allow programs to view the clipboard not in response to the paste command?

Yes in an ideal world where any application would only
do legal things, and where a phone or computer was used
by a unique user within the same work context (professional, private) it would help us to save time.

In any other case, this could easily lead to privacy
violation or company data leak or criminal data theft.

For example, after you copied an image, if you open Preview on a Mac, and it will read your clipboard and see you have pasted an image and offer you to create a new "Untitled" document from Clipboard. This function was conceived in an ideal world (the one where we don't need keys for car or house).

If this image is an unclassified document in an ideal world: no problem.
Otherwise, many potential problem with some of them with consequences which could be prosecuted (confidential information leak).

Comment: "This function was conceived in an ideal world (the one where we don't need keys for car or house)." So should we interpret this as: Apple's information security = shit?

Comment: @Mentalist Actually not. It means that here there’s a compromise being having features available for users and security. This is very common. In particular concerning pastes, this is a compromise where all the common operating systems lean toward features more than security. Actually Apple’s approach leans more towards security than most other mainstream operating systems have done for many years.

Comment: I agree with jksoegaard. @Mentalist In my answer to your closed question, I indicated one way that Apple's approach leans more towards security than other operating system, by providing named UIPasteBoard for apps to use if they so desire.