# Is Apple enabling phishing attacks through theft of iOS clipboard data? How to prevent?

Tags: iphone, security, settings, copy-paste, privacy

My iPhone disclosed a friend's name and address to an app without my permission by stealing clipboard contents. Good thing it wasn't financial information!

When I looked into the problem, I found [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/692572/why-are-iphone-apps-pasting-from-other-apps/):

> If you’re using an app that keeps pasting for no apparent reason, you
> might want to revoke its pasting permission. Unfortunately, as of iOS
> 14 and iPadOS 14, there is no way to stop an app from pasting. You
> won’t find any options for this under Settings > Privacy.

Is there really no way to stop Apple from giving random apps a backdoor to my clipboard contents?

For a company that claims to value customer privacy, this is unacceptable.

Passwords, credit card numbers, crypto wallet seed phrases, and other alphanumeric strings that are not easily committed to memory must be among the most frequently copy-pasted content. If one cannot entrust one's smartphone clipboard with that data, it's a serious concern.

Comment: I too will be interested to see what answers you get. My understanding is that open sharing between apps is the intended purpose of the clipboard/pasteboard on all Apple operating systems (and has been since 1983).

Comment: The change in iOS 14 was not to enable pasting (it has always been possible), rather to make it more obvious.

Comment: @Gilby I believe the original intention behind that design choice was to allow *users* to voluntarily drop their clipboard data into other computer programs when and where they wanted to. I don't believe the authorization of just any arbitrary software to hijack clipboard data at will, was ever part of the plan. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Gilby When you say "since 1983", I'm just curious, which pre-Macintosh platform are you referencing?

Comment: @Mentalist - any GUI has a pasteboard (or multiple ones) so back to the first ones e.g. Xerox Star For Apple the exact behaviour will be from NeXTStep started in 1989

Comment: @Mentalist Intention was for any other program to fetch what was on the clipboard, but that was expected to under the control of the user. Software has changed and the clipboard has not. I date the clipboard (pasteboard) to the Apple Lisa (1983).

Answer (score 2):

iOS supports not only the general clipboard (technically, the general UIPasteBoard), but also *named UIPasteBoards.*

As [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard) explain named UIPasteBoards:

> You can create named pasteboards with the class methods init(name:create:) and withUniqueName() for sharing data within your app and from your app to other apps that have the same Team ID.

From what I know, apps that want to better protect data that users may have pasted into the clipboard, would use named UIPasteBoards rather than the general one, to prevent the kind of stealing you were asking about.

Theoretically, on a jailbroken device, other apps may still be able to gain access to your app's named UIPasteBoard, so the app may want to implement other measures like encrypting data before transferring it to the named UIPasteBoard.

TLDR: Apple does support a feature, namely, named UIPasteBoards, to help prevent stealing of clipboard data, but leaves it to app developers to use this feature on an app by app basis.

Comment: Thank you for those details. If you have sensitive data in your Notes app, for example, and you copy it to your clipboard, what's to prevent another app from snatching that data from the clipboard, and selling user data like that in bulk to bad actors? Since Apple "leaves it to app developers to use this feature on an app by app basis" it seems like a potentially wide open vector for phishing attacks. Am I wrong or paranoid? I sure hope so...

Comment: @Mentalist Compared with android, for example, at least iOS provides named UIPasteBoards. I wonder why somebody downvoted my answer - did they have trouble implementing named UIPasteBoards?

Comment: It's always difficult to figure out downvotes. If I would have to guess, it might be related to the fact that the existance of `UIPasteBoards` doesn't help to solve the problem with applications that don't support it.

Comment: Thanks @nohillside ; I thought, though, that I addressed both questions that Mentalist had asked. 1) Apple follows a shared responsibility model, and provides `named UIPasteBoards` for apps that want to use it. (Apple says, "For sharing data with any other app, use the systemwide general pasteboard; for sharing data with another app from your team—that has the same team ID as the app to share from—use named pasteboards.") ; and 2) any way to prevent it? use named UIPasteBoards :-)